# Using Grub2 as a bootloader on a mac with a Firmware password in place

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, mac, bootloader

I am going to install linux on a work mac machine, I have permission to use Linux as my main OS but the company cannot remove the firmware password, which means I will not be able to dual boot the mac machine.

In my mind, if I just use grub as the main bootloader then all my problems will be averted as IT will enter the firmware password whenever I need it to.

I have admin rights to the machine.

Comment: When is this "firmware password" requested? What process asks for it?

Comment: My mistake, but this appears when you hold down the `alt` key when booting up the mac. I wonder if i shuld delete the question as its on a mac machine?

Comment: I would ask on [su] instead, yes. Or, even better, on [apple.se] (but make sure it's on topic there first, I'm not 100% sure). This sounds like it has nothing to do with  GRUB or Linux, it happens before GRUB is loaded and GRUB will not be able to affect it or bypass it. That said, I don't quite understand why you can't dual boot. From what you describe, you enter the password before the OS or bootloader are loaded.